# pass a class method to a function and call it

Tags: java

I have a function that I want to use to test the sorting time of various sorts. I have made an unorderedArray class to store my arrays and I define 4 different sorts in that class. I want to call this function and as a parameter pass it the exact method to call. This method lies in main and not the array class.

so here below, i would love to add another parameter which is the function and replace it with what I have now in `arrayObj.insertionSort();`

```
public static void testTime(UnOrderedArray arrayObj,String sort, String dataset){
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        arrayObj.insertionSort();
        long end = System.nanoTime();
        long timeTaken = end - start;
        System.out.println("The " + sort + " sort took "+timeTaken+" nanoseconds for a data set of " + dataset + "\n");
    }
```

Comment: You accept an interface that has the method you want to test. The caller can then either implement that interface directly or just use a method reference to reference that method (i.e. lambdas).

Comment: @JoachimSauer i think im following, do you mind whipping up a quick example?

Comment: Similar to @JoachimSauer answer, is to use a Visitor design pattern, which is basically very similar. The visitor is an interface, but by convention has a ```visit()``` method. To me, your code looks like you wish to time method calls, so using the Visitor pattern, or any interface you write with one method, you could pass it and call it where you currently have ```arrayObj.insertionSort()```. Any interface with a single method is known as a functional interface and will work with lambdas as @JoachimSauer mentioned.